# How do I exactly match a word with C#'s contains function?

Tags: c#, contains

I am trying to read out scripts through C# and determine if they contain certain words, but these words should be *identical to* instead of only containing what I'm looking for. Is there a way to use the `contains`-function, single out the word, and check if it is identical to the exact word?

How can I determine if it both *contains* and *is identical to* the search term?

Currently I am using the following script:

```
// GetScriptAssetsOfType<MonoBehaviour>() Returns all monobehaviour scripts as text
foreach (MonoScript m in GetScriptAssetsOfType<MonoBehaviour>())
{
    if (m.text.Contains("Material"))
    {
       // Identical check?
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't want to use an equal operator, you could trick it and say m.text.Contains("Material") && m.text.Length == 8

Comment: @Miche but the m.text length will always be longer then 8. As I am trying to single out that word in a huge text document, aka a script.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about a regex?

```
bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(m.text, @"\bMaterial\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another check inside. I hope I understood your problem.

```
// GetScriptAssetsOfType<MonoBehaviour>() Returns all monobehaviour scripts as text
foreach (MonoScript m in GetScriptAssetsOfType<MonoBehaviour>())
{
    if (m.text.Contains("Material"))
    {
        if(m.text == "Material")
        {
             //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That wont work. m.text sometimes = 1200 lines long. and i only want that single word that gets filtered by the contains to be checked if its equal to

Comment: You should use regex as what the other answers says. Another solution if you don't want to use regex is to split the words and then check it in a loop. You wont need contains tho

Answer (score 0):

just using extension method to make the Regex Handy

Extension class

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
        {
            public static class Extension
            {
                public static Match RegexMatch(this string input, string pattern, RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                {
                    return Regex.Match(input, pattern, regexOptions);
                }
            }
        }
```

and using of above class.

```
        using System.Text;
        namespace ConsoleApplication11
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    bool isMatch = "this is text ".RegexMatch(@"\bis\b").Success;
                }
            }
        }
```

see extension methods if not familiar http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/573095/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Extension-Methods-Named-Pa

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a regexp instead of Contains, now I understand your problem

```
string a = "This is a test for you";
string b = "This is a testForYou";
string c = "test This is a for you";
string d = "for you is this test.";
string e = "for you is this test, and works?";

var regexp = new Regex(@"(\stest[\s,\.])|(^test[\s,\.])");


Console.WriteLine(regexp.Match(a).Success);
Console.WriteLine(regexp.Match(b).Success);
Console.WriteLine(regexp.Match(c).Success);
Console.WriteLine(regexp.Match(d).Success);
Console.WriteLine(regexp.Match(e).Success);
```

Comment: I'm not a regexp pro, I'm pretty sure you can improve this

Answer (score -1):

Contains will search for the exact word you put as parameter
check this as example in a small program

```
string a = "This is a test";
string b = "This is a TEST";
Console.WriteLine(a.Contains("test"));
Console.WriteLine(b.Contains("test"));
```

Hope I understood well your problem

Comment: Yes in your test this might work. But if your script contains the word colorMaterial it will still find the Material. Making it not exact to anymore.