# contains method returns wrong value

Tags: c#, contains

I'm using `Contains()` to check if a string has a word and the method is returning true but there isn't the word I'm comparing.

Text:

> “Under the guise of Medicare for All and a Green New Deal, Democrats are embracing the same tired economic theories that have impoverished nations and stifled the liberties of millions over the past century,” Pence said to applause. “That system is socialism.
>
> “And the only thing green about the so-called Green New Deal is how much green it’s going to cost taxpayers if we do it: $90 million,” he said. Democrats have said the price tag would be lower than the figure Pence quoted.
>
> His comments to the Conservative Political Action Conference outside Washington continued a White House and Republican National Committee push to paint the opposition party as hellbent on making America’s economy one that is centrally planned from Washington and intent on taking money out of Americans’ pockets to finance a myriad social programs."

Searching word: "nation"

Do you know another way to do that search?

Comment: `"nation"` is indeed in the text you show. Do you mean you want to find it as a whole word only, so it doesn't match the `"nations"`?

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26013718/9555272

Comment: The important aspect here is this line from the [String.Contains docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2): "whether a specified *substring* occurs within this string". `Contains()` does not limit itself to searching whole words only.

Comment: the text contains National Committee too

Comment: @JordiJordi - That doesn't match. `Contains()` is case sensitive.

Comment: ok then sorry, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your search is returning `true` because the text contains "nations", which includes the string "nation".

If you want to search for the **word** "nation" and not include similar words like "nations", the easiest way is probably using regex and the `\b` metacharacter, which matches word boundaries.

```
bool found = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\bnation\b");
```

If you want to generalize this, you can write:

```
string search = "nation";
bool found = Regex.IsMatch(text, $@"\b{Regex.Escape(search)}\b");
```

As @Flydog57 helpfully pointed out in the comments, you can also do a case-insensitive search if that's what you're after:

```
string search = "nation";
bool found = Regex.IsMatch(text, $@"\b{Regex.Escape(search)}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: And if you don't care about case (you want to catch "Nation" as well as "nation"), you can create a case-insensitive Regex object (look for a Regex constructor that takes a Regex​Options parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Regex has its problems, as you need to understand very deeply how its mechanics are working and the potential for accidents or performance nightmares are big.
What I usually do is I destroy the text into little chunks and work with them.

Feel free to add stuff to the Split() method! Enjoy:

```
static bool findWord()
{
 var text = @"“Under the guise of Medicare for All and a Green New Deal, Democrats are embracing the same tired economic theories that have impoverished nations and stifled the liberties of millions over the past century,” Pence said to applause. “That system is socialism.

“And the only thing green about the so-called Green New Deal is how much green it’s going to cost taxpayers if we do it: $90 million,” he said. Democrats have said the price tag would be lower than the figure Pence quoted.

His comments to the Conservative Political Action Conference outside Washington continued a White House and Republican National Committee push to paint the opposition party as hellbent on making America’s economy one that is centrally planned from Washington and intent on taking money out of Americans’ pockets to finance a myriad social programs.";

var stringList = text.Split(' ', ',', ':', '.', '?', '“', '-'); // split the text into pieces and make a list
foreach (var word in stringList) // go through all items of that list
{
  if (word == "nation") return true;       
}
return false;
}
```